# Unable to create a redis instance in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis

I have trouble creating a redis instance using `gcloud` command
I think i have set thing properly.

```
gloud init
```

and post that i executed

```
gcloud redis instances create redis4quote --size=1 --region=asia-south1
```

and got the below error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.redis.instances.create) PERMISSION_DENIED: Write access to project 'xyz' was denied
```

Cant figure out why, seemed pretty staright forward.

Answer (score 0):

Well the error message is misleading. Memorystrore is not available in the region used in the command. When started with a us-central region the command executes. The error message is wrong.